# Problem with wifi, after seconds lose internet

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, internet

I have problems with some networks in Ubuntu 18.04
When I connect to the network, everything is fine.
A few seconds later (5/10 seconds) it stops working, from the browser I get `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET`

If I execute `ping 8.8.8.8` I get a similar result, the first few seconds works fine and then I stop getting a response.

- This started to happen to me when I changed the router. The router I bought is a tplink AX50 and all the devices in the house have been able to connect without problem, except my laptop with Ubuntu.
- it had already happened to me when trying to connect to some other networks
- I can also connect the laptop with ubuntu to the wifi of the cell phone.

I have seen many similar questions, but most have no answers and nothing has worked for me

If I execute `wireless-info`  from  https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info

In the first 5 this https://file.io/spiCULPLKDqC is te result.

20 seconds later, when the internet not work this is the result
https://file.io/UtgjgHSzgYfS

I can see some differences with meld, but I don't know anything about networks, the only one that catches my attention is the following

```
authenticate with <MAC 'OtraRed' [AC8]>
--
authenticate with <MAC 'OtraRed' [AC3]>
```

Answer (score 1):

After much testing the solution to this problem was simpler.
I had a docker network that collided with the defaultgateway of the new router.

```
br-7aaa6112e94b: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        ether 02:42:1d:07:cb:39  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I have removed the docker network and problem solved